# Insert into a certain position in a string

Tags: c#, string

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833111/c-sharp-insert-value-in-certain-position-in-string) to insert characters into a certain position into a string, but is it possible to insert a character into a string that is a variable length?

For example; I want to insert a substring `s = c + separator` into an existing string like this:

```
string c = "C"; string separator = "-";
                                              {s}
string1 = "MOT1-G-PRT45-100"; // "MOT1-G-PRT45-C-100"
```

or like this:

```
string c = "C"; string separator = null;
                                        {s}     
string2 = "MOT1GPRT45100"; // "MOT1GPRT45C100"
```

I have looked at the `string.Insert` method but I don't think I can use that in this instance. Does anyone have any other suggestions I might be able to use?

Note: the only part of the string that remains the same is there will *always* be a 3-digit number on the end of the string.

Comment: You can use string.Insert. Just insert `c+separator` at `string1.Length-4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
string s = "MOT1-G-PRT45-100";
int index = ... // position to insert
string res = s.Insert(index, c + separator);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do;

```
string c = "C"; string separator = "-";

string string1 = "MOT1-G-PRT45-100";

int position = 13;

string string2 = string1.Insert(position, string.Format("{0}{1}", c, separator));
```

Comment: `position = 13` won't work because the beginning of the string could be any length. eg `MOT1-100`

Comment: yes,this was an example,its up to you to decide the index.

Comment: @Ben..???,by your accepted answer please tell me what do you think is diferent,or what you dont understand?

Answer (score 0):

If there will always be a 3 digit number on the end, then it would be as simple as this:

```
string string1 = "MOT1-G-PRT45-100";
string c = "C", s = "-";
string1 = string1.Insert(string1.length-4,c+separator);
```