# Add comma sequentially to string in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a **string**.

```
string str = "TTFTTFFTTTTF";
```

How can I break this string and add character ","?

```
result should be- TTF,TTF,FTT,TTF
```

Comment: So you want to put comma after each 3 strings? is that correct?

Comment: Related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396048/c-sharp-elegant-way-of-partitioning-a-list

Comment: I will vote up for this question even if it is simple one but it has lead to many answers with different opinions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Join` after you've grouped by 3-chars:

```
var groups = str.Select((c, ix) => new { Char = c, Index = ix })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
    .Select(g => String.Concat(g.Select(x => x.Char)));
string result = string.Join(",", groups);
```

Since you're new to programming. That's a LINQ query so you need to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your code file.

- The `Select` extension method creates an anonymous type containing the char and the index of each char.
- `GroupBy` groups them by the result of `index / 3` which is an [integer division that truncates decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float). That's why you create groups of three.
- `String.Concat` creates a string from the 3 characters.
- `String.Join` concatenates them and inserts a comma delimiter between each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert`

**Insert** places one string into another. This forms a new string in your C# program. We use the string Insert method to place one string in the middle of another one—or at any other position.

**Tip 1:**
We can insert one string at any index into another. IndexOf can return a suitable index.

**Tip 2:**
Insert can be used to concatenate strings. But this is less efficient—concat, as with + is faster.

```
for(int i=3;i<=str.Length - 1;i+=4)
{
    str=str.Insert(i,",");
}
```

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ - What do u mean by buggy ?? you can have a look on [Insert Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Another smaller example can be viewed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24199187/3796048)

Comment: When you insert the first comma @MohitShrivastava you shift all subsequent characters by one, so your next `6` will not be in right position anymore.

Comment: @GSerg please have a look. Thanks for the error shown. I havent run it b4 posting.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava so I think you figure it out what buggy meant ;) lol

Comment: That new version is much worse. You can [have a play](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) before posting.

Comment: Btw Insert not insert and Length not length. The new code still does not works Have you tried it in c# 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple solution using `StringBuilder`

```
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 3)
    {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0},", str.Substring(i, 3));
    }
    stringBuilder.Length -= 1;
    str = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

I'm not sure if the following is better.

```
    stringBuilder.Append(str.Substring(i, 3)).Append(',');
```

I would suggest to avoid LINQ in this case as it will perform a lot more operations and this is a fairly simple task.

Comment: This is more efficient, all the more if the string is very large or it's used with many strings. But you need to take care of some edge cases. If the string length is not divisible through 3 this gives currently an error. If the string is empty you get another.