# Insert A Character After 7 Characters (C#)

Tags: c#

So each player in my game has a seven digit number that they are assigned. For example, if a player has an ID number of 0002232, how would I make it so that the ID number in game appears 000-2232. Basically, after three characters I want to add a "-".

Thanks! :)

Comment: a little bit of research or effort would help.

Comment: Why don't you try to look around in the documentation of the string class instead of asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Insert value in certain position in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833111/c-sharp-insert-value-in-certain-position-in-string)

Comment: I don't see how it's unclear, but I see how there is little research, and it's a duplicate ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You can use [String.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx).

**String.Insert**

```
public string Insert(
    int startIndex,
    string value
)

startIndex
Type: System.Int32
The zero-based index position of the insertion.
value
Type: System.String
The string to insert.
```

**Explanation**

This Method inserts a string into another string at the specified index position. The first parameter, `startIndex` is the zero-based index position of the insertion, and you want to insert it at the index position of `3`, and you want the first parameter to be `3`. The second parameter is the string to insert, and you want to insert `-`, so set the second parameter to a `-`.

**Code:**

```
string idnumber = "0002232";
string displayednumber = idnumber.Insert(3, "-");
```

**Result:**

```
displayednumber = "000-2232"
```

**Try it online**

http://rextester.com/LFDK8166

Comment: I already up voted this answer, but since I have less than 15 reputation points it won't show publicly. How do I accept this as an answer? :)

Comment: @OmarDajani, there is a check button underneath voting button. click on that check button to accept the answer and do accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @NoahCristino no problem :)