# How to insert a space after the first character?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like that for example

```
 T3123123 or A1238123
```

i want to put a space after the first letter in the string to be like

```
T 3123123 or A 1238123
```

I tried using Padright after the first character doesn't worked, i looked into regex and didn't figured out too , i'm asking for help not code

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  There are a variety of string manipulation functions on the `string` object, or taking the string as an array of characters and manipulating the array, etc.

Comment: I tried using padright but doesn't work ,  i look into regex but was't capable of using regex too so i came here asking for help not for code

Comment: Do you want a space after the first _letter_ or the first _character_ in the string?

Comment: First character, like the exemple i gave

Comment: I got it, using Insert thank u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert value into a string at a certain position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833111/insert-value-into-a-string-at-a-certain-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method `String.Insert(int startIndex, string val);`:

```
string x = "T12345";
x = x.Insert(1," ");
```

Comment: the Insert method return a new string. It does not edit the existing string.

Comment: @eKKiM: Strings are immutable.  *Every* modification to a string returns a new string.

Comment: yes, it is pretty obvious, because string is not modifiable. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

class stringReplace1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String str = "T3123123";

        Console.WriteLine("Original string: \"{0}\"", str);

        str = str.Insert(1, " ");

        Console.WriteLine(str);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You should use built in methods for characters and strings and all other type. They are pretty handy.

Answer (score -3):

**Using substrings:**

```
var input = "A123";
var output = input.Substring(0, 1) + " " + input.Substring(1);
```

http://rextester.com/YYCV60286

**Using an insert**

```
var input = "A123";
var output = input.Insert(1, " ");
```

http://rextester.com/UTGUU33130